# Simple Arithmetic with Simple Created Database in R

Tags: r, pipe, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to perform a few simple arithmetic commands via an equally simple database I have create.  Here is my database:

```
advertisement <- c("A", "B", "C")
times_shown <- c(900, 1000, 800)
clicks <- c(140, 180, 105)
leads <- c(55, 54, 40)


advertisement_all <- data.frame(advertisement, times_shown, clicks, leads)

advertisement_all(head)

advertisement times_shown clicks leads
1             A         900    140    55
2             B        1000    180    54
3             C         800    105    40
```

I would now like to perform the following three calculations:
(1) clicks / times_shown
(2) leads / clicks
(3) leads / times_shown

I would also like them grouped by advertisement (i.e., "A", "B", "C")

This is what I am (incorrectly) entering to perform these calculations:

```
advertisement_all %>%
  clicks /times_shown %>%
  leads / clicks %>%
  leads / times_shown %>%
  group_by(advertisement)
```

And this is the error message I receive:

```
advertisement_all %>%
+   clicks /times_shown %>%
+   leads / clicks %>%
+   leads / times_shown %>%
+   group_by(advertisement)
Error in clicks(.) : could not find function "clicks"
```

Your help is most appreciated.  Please note that I am new to R, so any assistance which is spelled out is not taken as an insult.  ; )

Comment: `advertisement_all %>%
  group_by(advertisement) %>%
  summarise( 
  clicks /times_shown ,
  leads / clicks ,
  leads / times_shown )`

Comment: Many thanks, Maydin!  Have a nice day.  = )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: Pipes are intended to pass the output of one function to another. Your code doesn't do that until you call `group_by` (presumably `dplyr::group_by`). Those rate calculations should be inside of a function like `dplyr::mutate` or `dplyr::summarise`, not just on their own